# Jquery inputmask not allowing integer input

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-inputmask

I am using the jquery inputmask library to control the user input for my form.
See https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

All I want is to ensure the user enters an integer 0-99.
So in my MVC application I have;

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Contract.ContractPeriodInWeeks, 
            new { style = "width:30px",  @data_inputmask="'mask': '99'" })
```

Yet this mask has no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you included `$('#Contract_ContractPeriodInWeeks').inputmask();` in your document ready function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i've been using inputmask in my asp mvc project too, and i got the same problem.

I've tried many things and managed to get it to work by adding it in a javascript right:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Contract.ContractPeriodInWeeks, 
        new { style = "width:30px" })
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#Contract_ContractPeriodInWeeks').inputmask('99');
</script>
```

Although i still don't know why you can't use input mask in the `object HtmlAttributes`, this should do the trick.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can put all the options in the data-inputmask attribute, but you still have to call .inputmask() on the element, it was never automatic.